# Как сделать себе на сайт новый дизайн гугл карт?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps, карты

Вроде как недавно гугл обновили дизайн карт. Теперь цвета более плоские, материал. Иконки тоже изменились и шрифты. Вот пример скриншотов

[image: Новый дизайн]

[image: Старый дизайн]

Answer (score 1):

**[Документация о создании собственных стилей карт Гугл](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)**, сообщает:

> Используя карту со стилями, вы можете настроить вид стандартных базовых карт Google, изменяя отображение таких элементов, как дороги, парки и районы застройки.
>
> Совет. Вы можете использовать стилизацию, чтобы запретить отображение
>   на карте организаций, достопримечательностей и других объектов. См.
>   **[пример скрытия объектов на карте с помощью стилей](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/hiding-features)**.

В следующем примере для карты используется стиль ночного режима с цветами, удобными для просмотра маршрута в темноте.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Styled Maps - Night Mode</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        // Styles a map in night mode.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 40.674, lng: -73.945},
          zoom: 12,
          styles: [
            {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
            {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
            {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]},
            {
              featureType: 'administrative.locality',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'poi',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'poi.park',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#263c3f'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'poi.park',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#6b9a76'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#38414e'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road',
              elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
              stylers: [{color: '#212a37'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#9ca5b3'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road.highway',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road.highway',
              elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
              stylers: [{color: '#1f2835'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road.highway',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#f3d19c'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'transit',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#2f3948'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'transit.station',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'water',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'water',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#515c6d'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'water',
              elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
              stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
            }
          ]
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Смотрите также **[документация для изменения стилей с JSON](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference)** ++ Создание настраиваемых стилей **[Styling Wizard: Google Maps APIs](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)**.

Comment: да я это видел. Мне как раз нужен стиль, как у гугл карты, а не ночной.

Comment: Примените Styling Wizard из моего ответа. Там много стилей.